# How to sort an Excel spreadsheet columns by row contents?

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, sorting

How do I sort the columns of an Excel spreadsheet? The `Sort` command from the `Data` menu only allows me to sort *rows* by the value of a *column*. I want to sort the **columns** alphabetically by the contents of a specific **row**.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It's a custom sort in the Data sorting.

From the *Data* tab click on the *Sort* button to open the Sort dialog box, click on *Options* to open the Sort Options dialog box and select *Sort left to right*. See [here](http://www.contextures.com/xlSort01.html#sorttwo) for more info.

[image: sort by row steps]

Comment: Me too :) my first answer was that it was not possible, then I decided to check

Comment: Great answer, especially with the illustrations -- thanks!

Comment: wish there were a way to do this in early versions

Comment: Normally excel advice can be applied to Google Sheets, but no custom sort in this case there :-(